# Is "in part" a counterpart of "in full" as in "They refunded my money in full/in part"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

I often hear people say "**The shop refunded my money in full**".

How to say that "**a shop refunded my money partially**"?

Can we say "**The shop refunded my money in part**"?

But that doesn't sound common.

Comment: The shop gave me a partial refund. The shop refunded part of my money.

Comment: Have you searched for "in part"? What did you find?

Comment: "Advance tickets that have already been bought cannot be refunded in part or in full" UK rail ticket web site (about cheap advance-purchase tickets when a cheaper fare becomes available)

Comment: You can have a look at this ngram. Apparently "money in part" is more common than "money partially"   
https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=money+in+part%2Cmoney+partially&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true#